# android fragment cannot open in the emulator

Tags: android, fragment

Firstly I'm new android and English :) sorry about that. I've a problem with Fragment manager. I read some code for using fragment in the main activity. However it's cannot run in emulator and also you can see the codes in below. I think the problem that about "import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;" line. I dont know maybe I must use it like that "import android.app.FragmenManager"
I hope you can understand my sentence and help me. 
Thank you.

```
   package com.example.ilk.fragmenttransactions;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void addA(View v){
        FragmentA f1 = new FragmentA();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f1, "A");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void removeA(View v){
        FragmentA f1 = (FragmentA)fm.findFragmentByTag("A");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        if(f1 != null){
            transaction.remove(f1);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "There is no A! you cannot delete it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void addB(View v){
        FragmentB f2 = new FragmentB();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f2, "B");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void removeB(View v){
        FragmentB f2 = (FragmentB)fm.findFragmentByTag("B");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        if(f2 != null){
            transaction.remove(f2);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, " There is no B! you cannot delete it ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: show the error message displayed in LogCat must be a requirement in StackOverFlow haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`.

the fragment is not loaded because you are not making any transaction when your app is initialized:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

i think you are trying to load the fragments by clicking an element of the layout with

`android:onClick` property

for example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="addA" />
```

that executes this method:

```
  public void addA(View v){
        FragmentA f1 = new FragmentA();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, f1, "A");
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Elena thank you for help I solved this problem. Absolutly you're right. I used fm = getSupportFragmentManager(); in onCreate method and it's ok Good night :)